# Allow selection of only 1 checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want allow selection of only 1 checkbox.
I am using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $('#valores input').on('change', function() {
        $('#valores input').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });
});
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="valores">              
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="valor" id="50reais" class="css-checkbox"/><label for="50reais" class="css-label radGroup1">R$ 50,00</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="valor" id="100reais" class="css-checkbox"/><label for="100reais" class="css-label radGroup1">R$ 100,00</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="valor" id="150reais" class="css-checkbox"/><label for="150reais" class="css-label radGroup1">R$ 150,00</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="valor" id="200reais" class="css-checkbox"/><label for="200reais" class="css-label radGroup1">R$ 200,00</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="valor" id="250reais" class="css-checkbox"/><label for="250reais" class="css-label radGroup1">R$ 250,00</label></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" name="valor" id="outroValor" class="css-checkbox"/><label for="outroValor" class="css-label radGroup1">Outro Valor</label></div>
</div>
```

Only works while the page is loading. After ready stops working.

Solved! There was an unnecessary script that I had left in the code and was causing this problem.

Thanks for all!

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/khLgjpmb/

Comment: Are you creating the inputs with javascript, or are they all part of the DOM when it loads?

Comment: Why not use radio buttons which is meant for your kind of situation?

Comment: In case you are creating checkboxes dynamically, try binding with the delegate version.  $('#valories').on('change', 'input', function(){ ... });

Comment: Ya, that's the purpose of radio buttons (except you cannot uncheck it). Using checkboxes may confuse your users.

Comment: Solved! There was an unnecessary script that I left in the code and was causing this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your page may be updating dynamically after load.

Change it to use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $(document).on('change', '#valores input', function() {
        $('#valores input').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
    });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/hrahs1gu/

*Also view your page DOM (e.g. Chrome F12 DOM inspector) after loading, so see if the elements are what you expect.*

Comment: Solved! There was an unnecessary script that I left in the code and was causing this problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <h3>Fruits</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Kiwi</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Jackfruit</label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />Mango
    </label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
    // in the handler, 'this' refers to the box clicked on
    var $box = $(this);
    console.log($box);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
      // the name of the box is retrieved using the .attr() method
      // as it is assumed and expected to be immutable
      var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $box.attr("name") + "']";
      // the checked state of the group/box on the other hand will change
      // and the current value is retrieved using .prop() method
      $(group).prop("checked", false);
      $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The original code (much shorter) also "works". There is obviously another problem, if it "stops working after page load".

Comment: Solved! There was an unnecessary script that I left in the code and was causing this problem.
Thanks!